# Yet Another Mail Merge - sending to multiple recipients

Tags: google-sheets, mail-merge

I'm required to send a parametrized mail message to multiple recipients, based on values in a Google spreadsheet. I've followed the instructions in this guide on how to use Yet Another Mail Merge.

http://www.thegoogleapps.com/2014/01/how-mail-merge-works-in-google-apps.html

However, e-mails aren't being sent to any address except for my own, despite the fact that the relevant row in the spreadsheet is marked as "done". To make this even weirder, when someone else uses the same spreadsheet (that is - the same physical file on Google drive, it's shared) he's able to send it to all the recipients, and it doesn't seem as though they're doing anything differently. I've tried changing the addresses, switching the data between rows, storing the file in another folder in my Google Drive. The row that arrives is always the one with my address, the others never arrive in the respective mail addresses.